# How does YARN decide to create how many containers? (Why the difference between S3a and HDFS?)

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hadoop-yarn

I'm using the current version of Hadoop, and running some **TestDFSIO** benchmarks (v. 1.8) to compare the cases where the default file system is HDFS versus the default file system is an S3 bucket (used via **S3a**).

When reading **100 x 1 MB** files with default file system as S3a, I observe the number of max containers in YARN Web UI is less than the case for HDFS as default, and S3a is about **4 times slower**.

When reading **1000 x 10 KB** files with default file system as S3a, I observe the number of max containers in YARN Web UI is at least **10 times less** than the case for HDFS as default, and S3a is about **16 times slower**. (E.g. 50 seconds of test execution time with HDFS default, versus **16 minutes** of test execution time with S3a default.)

The number of Launched Map Tasks is as expected in each case, there's no difference with respect to that. But **why** is YARN creating at least **10 times less** number of containers (e.g. 117 on HDFS versus 8 on S3a)? How does YARN decide to create how many number of containers when the cluster's vcores, RAM, and the job's input splits, and launched map tasks are the **same**; and **only the storage back-end** is different?

It might be of course fine to expect a performance difference between HDFS versus Amazon S3 (via S3a) when running the same TestDFSIO jobs, what I'm after is understanding how YARN is deciding the number of max containers it launches during those jobs, where only the default file system is changed, because currently, it is like, when the default file system is S3a, YARN is almost not using 90% of the parallelism (which it normally does when the default file system is HDFS).

The cluster is a 15-node cluster, with 1 NameNode, 1 ResourceManager (YARN), and 13 DataNodes (worker nodes). Each node has 128 GB RAM, and 48-core CPU. This is a dedicated testing cluster: during TestDFSIO test runs, nothing else runs on the cluster.

For HDFS, the `dfs.blocksize` is `256m`, and it uses 4 HDDs (`dfs.datanode.data.dir` is set to `file:///mnt/hadoopData1,file:///mnt/hadoopData2,file:///mnt/hadoopData3,file:///mnt/hadoopData4`).

For S3a, `fs.s3a.block.size` is set to `268435456`, that is 256m, same as HDFS default block size.

The Hadoop tmp directory is on an SSD (by setting `hadoop.tmp.dir` to `/mnt/ssd1/tmp` in `core-site.xml`, and also setting `mapreduce.cluster.local.dir` to `/mnt/ssd1/mapred/local` in `mapred-site.xml`)

The performance difference (default HDFS, versus default set to S3a) is summarized below:

```
TestDFSIO v. 1.8  (READ)    

fs.default.name                # of Files x Size of File   Launched Map Tasks   Max # of containers observed in YARN Web UI Test exec time sec
=============================  =========================   ==================   ===========================================     ==================
hdfs://hadoop1:9000            100  x  1 MB                 100                 117                                               19
hdfs://hadoop1:9000            1000 x 10 KB                1000                 117                                               56
s3a://emre-hadoop-test-bucket  100  x  1 MB                 100                  60                                               78
s3a://emre-hadoop-test-bucket  1000 x 10 KB                1000                   8                                             1012
```

[image: 100 x 1 MB - default FS HDFS versus default FS S3a]

[image: 1000 x 10 KB - default FS HDFS versus default FS S3a]

Comment: What is your Hadoop version? What shuffle backend are you using?

Comment: Also what are your jvm reuse settings?

Comment: Yet another question that came into my mind: was your job running in "Uber" mode?

Comment: @ThomasJungblut I'm using `hadoop 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT` (built from trunk and a few patches).  If by "shuffle backend" you mean `yarn.nodemanager.aux-services`, it is set to `mapreduce_shuffle`.  As for JVM reuse settings, as far as I can see I didn't do anything regarding that, so it should be whatever the default is (which particular properties are you referring to? (to be sure)). The runs were not in "Uber" mode, because TestDFSIO reports "... running in uber mode : false".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short, one of the important criteria [YARN](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YARN.html) uses to decide how many containers to create is based on **data locality**. When using a non-HDFS file system, such as [S3a](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3) to connect to Amazon S3, or another S3-compatible object store, it is the responsibility of the file system to give information about the data locality because in such a case, none of the data is local to a node, each node needs to retrieve the data from the network, or, from another perspective, each node has the same data locality.

The previous paragraph explains the container creation behavior I've observed when running Hadoop MapReduce jobs against Amazon S3, using S3a file system. In order to fix the issue, I've started to work on a patch, and the development will be tracked via [HADOOP-12878](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-12878).

Also see the following:

- [SO question:hadoop/yarn and task parallelization on non-hdfs filesystems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25269964/hadoop-yarn-and-task-parallelization-on-non-hdfs-filesystems)
- [Mail list thread: hadoop/yarn and task parallelization on non-hdfs filesystems](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hadoop-hdfs-user/201408.mbox/%3CCADSD3vhDqkfLNV9VYg8R8KBDjJ4=Dwv2O8psHr2uB7zZgfP6=A@mail.gmail.com%3E)